# Display manager that works well with multiple displays and multiple sacling

Tags: linux-mint, display-manager

I am looking for a display manager that works with multiple displays and multiple scaling. I am running Linux Mint on a laptop with a 4k screen. I also have a 1440p portable monitor and a 1440p ultra-wide desktop monitor.

While I can connect these displays together if I use different scaling on the different monitors (as you want when you have a big 1440p display paired to a small 4k display) it tends to break badly, with a variety of issues occurring.

Therefore I am looking for a different display manager which is capable of handling two or more displays with different scaling on each display.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658619/which-linux-distros-have-good-multi-monitor-support-for-differing-dpi-scaling-a

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I'm looking for a new display manager for my existing distro. Not to completely hop distro's. I like linux but I'm not one of those people who likes to constantly hop distro's